# ¿Puedo trabajar en google colabs con alguien más a la misma vez?

Tags: google-colab

resulta que debo trabajar en google colabs con un compañero, pero al momento de guardar cuando estamos trabajando a la misma vez nos arroja algunos errores, entonces me nace la pregunta si existe algo así como un pull request para poder guardar lo que uno ha hecho. muchas gracias